# Kth Order statistic of a multivariate distribution

Tags: order-statistics, multivariate-distribution

The Kth order statistic for a univariate is equal to its kth-smallest value. For instance, given $\{6,9,3,8\}$, the 2nd-smallest value would be the 2nd order statistic.

How does this concept generalize in the case of multivariate distribution?
For instance let us say, we have four bivariate samples $\{\{5,3\}, \{1,6\}, \{2,3\}, \{4,2\}\}$. How can one define the 2nd order statistic?

Comment: My topology class had no problem with defining a "dictionary" order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where, much like when we alphabetize words, we look at the first digit, and if there is a tie, we look at the second digit, and if there is a tie...

Comment: It depends on how you wish to order $\mathbb{R}^n:$ what do you have in mind?  Note that no real dimension higher than $1$ supports a total order that enjoys all the properties of the usual ordering of the line.

Comment: Mmm okey @dave, that would be my first shot as well, nevertheless I see some sort of "discontinuity" when we pass from, for instance {1,9} to {2,1}.  I thought other ordering would exists

Comment: For lexicographic order and with many variables, this question reduces to the univariate case.  With continuous distributions almost surely the order will be determined by the first marginal.  Discrete distributions with finite support are essentially univariate anyway.  For other discrete distributions, lexicographic order gives a tie-breaker, which isn't a conceptual complication (and formulas are already complicated enough even in the univariate case due to the need to account for ties).